Word or Excel - Hyperlink that goes to a controlled text box
Want to make x" by x" text boxes that allow someone to enter text, format, and use select colors (if possible). I've done this before but it's been years and my guide book was lost in a fire. Normally I'd go there but now I'm not sure if I'm looking for the right thing or calling it the right thing. I make decals and would like clients to get a constricted word box that won't allow them to go over the space they choose; there are specific size availability. So, I don't need it to be too personal. Any help if I'm using the right words to look it up or point me the right way. Super savvy just lost for the right words at this point.
Tried looking controlled text boxes and hyperlinks. I know how to make hyperlinks to a box. I don't remember how to control what someone uses in that text box anymore.
